# Network wide rep graph is not large enough

Tags: bug, status-norepro, network-profile, reputation-graph

It seems my [network wide rep graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/6241661/wythagoras?tab=reputation) is not large enough to hold all my sites:

[image]

The label of the German Language site partially falls of the chart.

I only see the problem on Firefox. There is no problem on Chrome or on Safari.

Comment: It looks fine for me on Chrome 53.0.2785.143.

Comment: No problem for me with Pale Moon 26.5.

Comment: Seems fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE 11 and Opera - do you have a better repro?

Comment: @Sklivvz No, it seems fixed right now. I think the issue was still there yesterday, I have no idea why it it different now.

Comment: @Sklivvz: While I don't see any actual overflow, I definitely see a difference in the line spacing between Firefox and Chrome. Surprisingly, it seems to be reflected in the generated SVG code itself: e.g. for the "German Language" entry, Firefox's DOM inspector shows `<text x="30" y="338" [...]`, whereas on Chrome I see `<text x="30" y="298" [...]` instead. So the next question is, how does highcharts calculate these positions, and why is it apparently browser-dependent? In any case, this seems like a bug in highcharts.

Comment: ... In any case, I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that, with the configuration SE is currently using, highcharts seems to generate two different and conflicting `font-family` CSS properties for each piece of text on the chart.