# SE reputation graph has broken labels

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

Dem Y-axis labels...

[image: Screenshot of the reputation graph]

There seems to be a slightly too large gap between the numbers, so they get increasingly offset from the line they're supposed to annotate (moving upwards).

It's vaguely possible to intuit what's going on (particularly as I know I'm about to hit 300k on SO) but it really makes a not-clear graph!

---

Bonus bug: if you zoom in, the labels are even worse, then when you *Reset Zoom* things like this happen:

[image: Screenshot of it being EVEN WORSE after zooming in and back out]

Nice.

---

<sup>Chrome 74, Windows 10 Home</sup>

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296884/network-reputation-graph-becomes-nervous-when-clicking-quickly-backs-away-slowl (different issue but in the comments the odd labeling behavior is mentioned / noticed)

Comment: let me also link to [this status-norepro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285692/158100) as I think Ilmari Karonen has some insightful observations that might help diagnosing this bug. Or at least confirm if it is a Highcharts bug or not.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288238/markers-are-placed-incorrectly-on-network-profile-reputation-graph-after-zoom-re

Comment: @rene Yeah almost - this started as a different bug (the labels _start_ in the wrong place) though I later discovered the zoom problem too which is the same